# How to add id for the date picker dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am looking forward to do add more  option in that one text box two date picker and text area.here date pickers are working based id attribute but that is not changed in dynamically added row how to solve this problem below is the example code using textbox

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/bootstrapValidator.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- form: -->
        <section>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Dynamic fields</h2>
                </div>

                <form id="defaultForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="target.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Textbox</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="textbox[]" placeholder="Textbox #1" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm addButton" data-template="textbox">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group hide" id="textboxTemplate">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm removeButton">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>               


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- :form -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.addButton').on('click', function() {
            var index = $(this).data('index');
            if (!index) {
                index = 1;
                $(this).data('index', 1);
            }
            index++;
            $(this).data('index', index);

            var template     = $(this).attr('data-template'),
                $templateEle = $('#' + template + 'Template'),
                $row         = $templateEle.clone().removeAttr('id').insertBefore($templateEle).removeClass('hide'),
                $el          = $row.find('input').eq(0).attr('name', template + '[]');
            $('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator('addField', $el);

            // Set random value for checkbox and textbox
            if ('checkbox' == $el.attr('type') || 'radio' == $el.attr('type')) {
                $el.val('Choice #' + index)
                   .parent().find('span.lbl').html('Choice #' + index);
            } else {
                $el.attr('placeholder', 'Textbox #' + index);
            }

            $row.on('click', '.removeButton', function(e) {
                $('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator('removeField', $el);
                $row.remove();
            });
        });

        $('#defaultForm')
            .bootstrapValidator({
                message: 'This value is not valid',
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    'textbox[]': {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The textbox field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'checkbox[]': {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The checkbox field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'radio[]': {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The radio field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .on('error.field.bv', function(e, data) {
                //console.log('error.field.bv -->', data.element);
            })
            .on('success.field.bv', function(e, data) {
                //console.log('success.field.bv -->', data.element);
            })
            .on('added.field.bv', function(e, data) {
                //console.log('Added element -->', data.field, data.element);
            })
            .on('removed.field.bv', function(e, data) {
                //console.log('Removed element -->', data.field, data.element);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Do you create datepicker on id or class?

Comment: id="fromdatePicker" id="todatePicker" these are working when i add more next generated date picker is not working

Comment: check the response, if it still not works add more code to show how are you invoking date range picker

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="input-group input-append date" id="fromdatePicker1"></div>
<div class="input-group input-append date" id="fromdatePicker2"></div>
```

jQuery

```
// get the last DIV which ID starts with ^= "fromdatePicker"
var $div = $('div[id^="fromdatePicker"]:last');

// Read the Number from that DIV's ID (i.e: 2 from "fromdatePicker2")
// And increment that number by 1
var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;

// Clone it and assign the new ID (i.e: from num 3 to ID "klon3")
var $fromdatePicker = $div.clone().prop('id', 'fromdatePicker'+num );

// >>> Append $fromdatePicker wherever you want
```

to invoke date range picker

```
$('div[id="fromdatePicker^"]').daterangepicker();
```

or use class instead

```
$('.common-class-name').daterangepicker();
```

Live Demo

> http://jsbin.com/bekabegelo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: is it possible to do like this  $el = $row.find('input').eq(0).attr('name', template + '[]');

Comment: After removing $row = $templateEle.clone().removeAttr('id')  use .attr( 'id', $fromDatePicker);

Comment: i did not get you

Comment: Added demo link in answer